# haproxy node_exporter for prometheus

Tags: haproxy, prometheus

I did have haproxy balancing HTTP and HTTPS traffic from Internet to WEB service.
I want to monitoring this service via Prometheus.
On GitHub did find application [enter link description here](https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter)
HAProxy Exporter for Prometheus

Did collect integration and did get result:

```
# HELP go_gc_duration_seconds A summary of the GC invocation durations.
# TYPE go_gc_duration_seconds summary
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.25"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.5"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="0.75"} 0
go_gc_duration_seconds{quantile="1"} 0.0010511
go_gc_duration_seconds_sum 0.0126325
go_gc_duration_seconds_count 487
# HELP go_goroutines Number of goroutines that currently exist.
# TYPE go_goroutines gauge
go_goroutines 9
# HELP go_info Information about the Go environment.
# TYPE go_info gauge
go_info{version="go1.10.3"} 1
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes Number of bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_alloc_bytes 2.786048e+06
# HELP go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total Total number of bytes allocated, even if freed.
# TYPE go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total counter
go_memstats_alloc_bytes_total 1.581756e+07
# HELP go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes Number of bytes used by the profiling bucket hash table.
# TYPE go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_buck_hash_sys_bytes 1.446972e+06
# HELP go_memstats_frees_total Total number of frees.
# TYPE go_memstats_frees_total counter
go_memstats_frees_total 22024
# HELP go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction The fraction of this program's available CPU time used by the GC since the program started.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction gauge
go_memstats_gc_cpu_fraction -9.069464256116777e-09
# HELP go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for garbage collection system metadata.
# TYPE go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_gc_sys_bytes 405504
# HELP go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes Number of heap bytes allocated and still in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_alloc_bytes 2.786048e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes Number of heap bytes waiting to be used.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_idle_bytes 1.859584e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes Number of heap bytes that are in use.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_inuse_bytes 3.97312e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_objects Number of allocated objects.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_objects gauge
go_memstats_heap_objects 8515
# HELP go_memstats_heap_released_bytes Number of heap bytes released to OS.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_released_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_released_bytes 1.818624e+06
# HELP go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes Number of heap bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_heap_sys_bytes 5.832704e+06
# HELP go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds Number of seconds since 1970 of last garbage collection.
# TYPE go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds gauge
go_memstats_last_gc_time_seconds 1.5312108789824975e+09
# HELP go_memstats_lookups_total Total number of pointer lookups.
# TYPE go_memstats_lookups_total counter
go_memstats_lookups_total 67
# HELP go_memstats_mallocs_total Total number of mallocs.
# TYPE go_memstats_mallocs_total counter
go_memstats_mallocs_total 30539
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mcache structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_inuse_bytes 13632
# HELP go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mcache structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mcache_sys_bytes 16384
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by mspan structures.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_inuse_bytes 35416
# HELP go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for mspan structures obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_mspan_sys_bytes 49152
# HELP go_memstats_next_gc_bytes Number of heap bytes when next garbage collection will take place.
# TYPE go_memstats_next_gc_bytes gauge
go_memstats_next_gc_bytes 4.194304e+06
# HELP go_memstats_other_sys_bytes Number of bytes used for other system allocations.
# TYPE go_memstats_other_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_other_sys_bytes 1.561788e+06
# HELP go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes Number of bytes in use by the stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_inuse_bytes 458752
# HELP go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system for stack allocator.
# TYPE go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_stack_sys_bytes 458752
# HELP go_memstats_sys_bytes Number of bytes obtained from system.
# TYPE go_memstats_sys_bytes gauge
go_memstats_sys_bytes 9.771256e+06
# HELP go_threads Number of OS threads created.
# TYPE go_threads gauge
go_threads 14
# HELP haproxy_exporter_build_info A metric with a constant '1' value labeled by version, revision, branch, and goversion from which haproxy_exporter was built.
# TYPE haproxy_exporter_build_info gauge
haproxy_exporter_build_info{branch="",goversion="go1.10.3",revision="",version=""} 1
# HELP haproxy_exporter_csv_parse_failures Number of errors while parsing CSV.
# TYPE haproxy_exporter_csv_parse_failures counter
haproxy_exporter_csv_parse_failures 0
# HELP haproxy_exporter_total_scrapes Current total HAProxy scrapes.
# TYPE haproxy_exporter_total_scrapes counter
haproxy_exporter_total_scrapes 17
# HELP haproxy_up Was the last scrape of haproxy successful.
# TYPE haproxy_up gauge
haproxy_up 0
# HELP http_request_duration_microseconds The HTTP request latencies in microseconds.
# TYPE http_request_duration_microseconds summary
http_request_duration_microseconds{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.5"} 6996.2
http_request_duration_microseconds{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.9"} 7012.1
http_request_duration_microseconds{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.99"} 7012.1
http_request_duration_microseconds_sum{handler="prometheus"} 104494.6
http_request_duration_microseconds_count{handler="prometheus"} 16
# HELP http_request_size_bytes The HTTP request sizes in bytes.
# TYPE http_request_size_bytes summary
http_request_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.5"} 392
http_request_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.9"} 392
http_request_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.99"} 392
http_request_size_bytes_sum{handler="prometheus"} 6250
http_request_size_bytes_count{handler="prometheus"} 16
# HELP http_requests_total Total number of HTTP requests made.
# TYPE http_requests_total counter
http_requests_total{code="200",handler="prometheus",method="get"} 16
# HELP http_response_size_bytes The HTTP response sizes in bytes.
# TYPE http_response_size_bytes summary
http_response_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.5"} 1502
http_response_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.9"} 1520
http_response_size_bytes{handler="prometheus",quantile="0.99"} 1520
http_response_size_bytes_sum{handler="prometheus"} 23859
http_response_size_bytes_count{handler="prometheus"} 16
```

May be you know other app are ready-made modules for collect HAProxy metrics: for example current conns, https-in/Frontend/Session rate/current conns and others simular Prometheus node_exporter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among your output:

```
# HELP haproxy_up Was the last scrape of haproxy successful.
# TYPE haproxy_up gauge
haproxy_up 0
```

Either haproxy or the exporter isn't configured correctly, make sure you've followed the [usage instructions](https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter#usage).

Comment: I did forget to addition authitication in parameter --haproxy.scrape-uri. Thank You!!!